# Why maven test dependency include compile dependency?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, dependencies

I do a `mvn dependendy:tree` and get something like:

```
|
+- some.dependency:for-test:jar:1.2.3:test    <---- for test only
   +- ...
   +- ...
   +- some.other.dependency:big-dependency:jar:compile  <---- include compile dependency?
      +- lots.of.big:dependencies
```

Question: Why would a test dependency bring compile dependencies?

Sub-question: I am asking because I try to reduce the size of a shaded jar. How do I get ride of those?

Note: in the tree, the included compiled dependency `some.other.dependency:big-dependency` appear nowhere else in the tree.

Comment: Do you see it also in dependency:list?

Comment: Yes, it is there too. :list looks the same without the hierarchy

Comment: `compile` dependencies of `test` dependencies become `test` dependencies automatically, unless they are either declared elsewhere or some dependencyManagement overrides the scope.